# Multiple record table form - one column per record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an association proxy of ActiveRecord objects (same class), I need to build a single form for all those object.

This would be pretty easy if only customer didn't requested those to be in a horizontally scrollable table with each record fields being in separate columns.

This is what I am currently doing to implement this:

```
<%= form_tag submission_path do %>
  <% object_forms = @objects.map {|o| fields_for("object[#{o.to_param}]", o) {|f| break f}} %>
  <table>
    <% @attributes.each do |attr| %>
      <tr>
        <% object_forms.each do |f| %>
          <td><%= f.text_field attr %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
  <%= submit_tag 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

This works perfectly, however I am not very keen on storing form builder in an array. Also number of iterations is pretty big (In fact this should not be a problem as they don't expect large numbers here, but in general it might be a problem) Is there any better way to implement this?